# Rhythmic vocal traditions

Tags: history

Most musical vocal traditions seem to be melodic, i.e. singing. However, of course, rapping exists, which is rhythmic.

The question I have is, what other musical vocal styles exist that are primarily rhythmic?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Talking Blues** is musical style involving rhythmic talking, typically over a blues chord progression. A favourite example of mine is the verses of Johnny Cash's *One piece at a time*.

The **Haka** is a traditional Maori war cry that is now better known from its performances by the [All Blacks](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/New_Zealand_national_rugby_union_team). Similarly, the Tongans are known for their **Sipi Tau**.

**Bid Calling** is a rhythmic and somewhat musical vocal style that has been developed by auctioneers in the United States.

Comment: By no means comprehensive - just a few to start us off!

Answer (score 1):

**Eefing** (or 'eephing') is a kind of fast Appalachian yodel that is so fast that it has little sense of a melody, and is sometimes described (uncharitably) as Hillbilly beatboxing - **beatboxing** being a more recent rhythmic vocal style that originated as an imitation of drum machines and turntablist techniques.

Some traditional nursery rhymes (particularly **skipping/clapping rhymes**) are often chanted with no melody - such as *Piggy on the railway* and *I tiddly eye tie eat brown bread*. These could be seen as a kind of poetry - another form of poetry that emphasises rhythm in its performance is **dub poetry**, itself a cousin of Jamaican **toasting** techniques that may be melodic, but are also sometimes primarily rhythmic (for example, Smiley Culture's *Cockney Translation*) and are in turn one of the roots of rap music.